# Symfony default locale and routing

Tags: symfony, localization

I have a locale selector as a list of links to home like this:

```
<ul id="menu-locale">
    <li id="li-locale_es">
        <a href="{{path('home', {'_locale': 'es'})}}"><span class="rotulo-locale">Castellano</span><span class="flag flag_es"></span></a>
    </li>
    <li id="li-locale_en">
        <a href="{{path('home', {'_locale': 'en'})}}"><span class="rotulo-locale">English</span><span class="flag flag_en"></span></a>
    </li>
    <li id="li-locale_de">
        <a href="{{path('home', {'_locale': 'de'})}}"><span class="rotulo-locale">Deutsch</span><span class="flag flag_de"></span></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And home route is defined like this:

```
/**
 * @Route("/", name="home_default_locale")
 * @Route("/{_locale}", name="home", defaults={"_locale" = "es"}, requirements={"_locale" = "[a-z]{2}"})
 */
public function homeAction()
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $locale = $this->getRequest()->getLocale();
    etc...
}
```

The problem is, when redirecting to `{{path('home', {'_locale': 'es'})}}` it actually redirects to `/` instead of `/es` which makes the controller to get last active locale instead of `es`. I guess the `$locale = $this->getRequest()->getLocale();` is the wrong bit as it takes active locale instead of the given one,

but what should I do instead of that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should omit `defaults={"_locale" = "es"}` in your second route definition.

You have conflicting route definitions `/` and `/{_locale}` as if `_locale` is set to your default `es` your route will be not `/es` but `/` that will conflict with the firstly defined route.

Comment: The problem I have is `/` must be a valid route as it is used in public links, what can I do then?

Comment: If you don't provide value for `_locale` it is always set to the fallback locale that is configured in your `config.yml`. In your case your locale was also  set to `es` locale as you define it in route definition.